# Offer reputation to OP to add bounty to the question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I assume SO has very good answer to question ratio but I am just giving my thoughts to improve it further.

Can system offer some reputation from himself to OP when he didnt get his answer in some time duration (in addition to 2 days) and want to add bounty to the question?

I think, some times the OP didnt want to add bounty to the question as he himself don't have much reputation (but considering he just enough reputation to add bounty)

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not going to happen.

You can post bounties on another question, it doesn't have to be your own question. As such, there is *no need* to transfer reputation to another account here.

Transferring reputation like this would only be abused, to give question-ban evaders a chance to promote another question without much community visibility. Or a chance for a sock puppet to transfer reputation to another account via a third party to hide the transfer. The possibilities for abuse are staggering.

Comment: I understood what you are saying, but like just offering reputation of 25% of the bounty amount only on adding the bounty action.

Comment: @Garry: again, that is prone to abuse. Someone needs to care enough about the post front the whole bounty. Bounty clustering will lead to sock accounts chipping in together to boost the standing of another account otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I can understand that stopping the abuse of system is more important.